# how can i nest two state with a return array within a class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dom, event-handling

Attached below is my current code here..

```
 
<ul className={`nav_links ${isNavShowing ? "show_nav" : "hide_nav"}`}>
                {
                    links.map(({name, path }, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <NavLink to={path} className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active-nav" : ""}  onClick={() => setIsNavShowing (prev => !prev)}>{name}</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        )   
                    })
                }
            </ul>
```

so it happens that, I intend to change the color of my nav link when scroll. ordinarily, **I should have had it like this**

```
<ul className={`nav_links ${isNavShowing ? "show_nav" : "hide_nav"}`}>
                {
                    links.map(({name, path }, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <NavLink to={path} className={  `scllValue > 0 ? 'scrolling' : ''} key={i} $({isActive}) => isActive ? "active-nav" : ""`}  onClick={() => setIsNavShowing (prev => !prev)}>{name}</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        )   
                    })
                }
            </ul>
```

but i am a little bit confused because the new return state has some arrays which are map as shown below.

```
{[...Array(4)].map((e, i) => (
                < className={scllValue > 0 ? 'scrolling' : ''} key={i}>Some content</>
            ))}
```

so any idea on how to include the new state with a return array that is destructed via **.map**

Comment: anyone please ?